# How to import correctly an android app?

Tags: android, import, project, android-manifest

I have some apps in eclipse and I exported my apps, but when I import all apps again, and when I import it, I have 1 error in Androidmanifest.xml (for the package name) and the code has not appeared. I have not updated my SDK manager. Could that be the problem?

I tried to put the project name in the manifest, and I don't get more errors in it, but when I export, it doesn't save all my information/configuration.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project? That might fix the issue. Another thing to try is checking other questions on Stack Overflow, and/or the provided Android documentation.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan You know? everytime i click Clean, the project get error in R. I always need to wait to the next day, and some times, R dissappear for ever. I dont understand the "clean" button really

Comment: It basically erases all the other builds and starts fresh (you should always build after a clean). That sometimes happens to me too.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan Ok i will try, but first i will update sdk manager because i cancelled it and get bugs in Eclipse ._.

Comment: update your question to show error message.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan I tried cleaning the project and i have the option activated of building automatically, but.. Now i have error in the code activity.java (in everyone of every project) "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed"... and the details is this error (really this is stupid)

Comment: Try uninstalling (or deleting, since Eclipse doesn't "install" per se) Eclipse and reinstalling it. That should definitely do the trick.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan i did it some times, i will paste the code like indians and its ok :D
Thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. I am a novice to android studio and to creating android apps. I downloaded sample apps from the android site but could not get it to run inside of android studio. What I was doing was allowing the android studio ADT to convert the project. This was a mistake. I ended up importing the project but not allowing the ADT to migrate any part of the unzipped project file. Once I did this the ability to run the apps was there and I just had to link the dependencies via the project structure option under File in the top toolbar and then worked out minor issues that were mentioned in the console of the log. This is probably a different issue than what is discussed here but it does relate to the importing and  running of android apps.